# Performing "exact" G-tests in R with contingency table samples using `r2dtable`

Tags: r, count-data, contingency-tables, exact-test

I am interested in performing the "exact" versions of G-tests of independence in R with nonparametric table enumeration after having been told that this could help with achieving more accurate $p$-values at lower expected sample counts compared to the default, more "approximate" test that just calculates a single $G$ value for the realized table. Of course, I am not super familiar with this notion and how it has been borne out in statistics literature, so if this is wrong or inaccurate, please correct me.

Apparently, this is straightforward to do with the base R `r2dtable` function that uses Patefield's 1981 $r \times c$ table randomization algorithm. Hence, above I put "exact" in quotes to accommodate the situation where tables are sampled/simulated, rather than fully enumerated. However, I am having trouble finding example code depicting how G-test statistic enumeration and ordering from more to less extreme via the samples from `r2dtable` (or `rhyper`) would work.

Consequently, I have four questions. Perhaps the first three are mostly directly relevant for CrossValidated.

- With the lack of examples I have found, I am worried I may have misunderstood what I was told, though ordering contingency tables conditioned on margins by $G$ values instead of probabilities (as in Fisher's exact testing) makes sense to me. Is it fine to use $G$ or $\chi^2$ as a means of table ordering?
- If "exact" G-testing is a functional scheme, does it indeed afford more $p$-value accuracy with lower expected samples than an "approximate" G-test?
- With table enumeration happening in all three methods, are "exact" G-and "exact" $\chi^2$ testing results comparable to Fisher's exact test for tables with the same margins?
- The implementation question: potentially even in pseudocode, what would the steps be to conduct "exact" G-testing with `r2dtable` or `rhyper` in R?

For the fourth question, say we have a contingency table as follows:

```
test_matrix <-
matrix(c(23, 120, 17, 125), nrow = 2,
       dimnames = list(disease1 = c("died", "survived"),
                       disease2 = c("died", "survived")))

row_tot <- rowSums(test_matrix)
col_tot <- colSums(test_matrix)
n <- sum(row_tot)
```

and then with something like `r2dtable(1000, row_tot, col_tot)`, is the process as straightforward as obtaining expected cell count values $E_{ci}$ with `chisq.test` on each of the sampled tables (using $c$ to index the contingency table and $i$ the cell number for that table) and then doing the $G$-test calculations with `sapply`?

Comment: 1) I think p-values derived from simulations like this are typically referred to as "simulated" rather than "exact." 2) I have a package to do this in R: https://github.com/josh-mc/discretefit but yes the process is a simple as you suppose.

Comment: Written in C++ too, nice, I'll definitely check out that package.

Comment: @num_39 I've seen instances of both, which might come about since they're simulated from the exact null distribution; one can make them as near to the exact values as desired by simulating long enough.

Comment: @Glen_b, true but at least for those who work on such things, the difference between an algorithm that establishes exact p-values and a simulation is immense, e.g. exact p-values for a discrete KS test https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2011/RJ-2011-016/RJ-2011-016.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many possible solutions, but you only need to generate many tables and apply the `g.test` to all of them. I use a pre-programmed `g.test` function from CRAN:

```r
library(AMR) 

test_matrix <-
  matrix(c(23, 120, 17, 125), nrow = 2,
         dimnames = list(disease1 = c("died", "survived"),
                         disease2 = c("died", "survived")))

stat_obs <- suppressWarnings(AMR::g.test(test_matrix))$statistic

row_tot <- rowSums(test_matrix)
col_tot <- colSums(test_matrix)
n <- sum(row_tot)

B <- 1000000 
statistics <- numeric(B)
pvals <- numeric(B)
set.seed(7*11*13)
for (i in 1:B) {
  ob <- suppressWarnings(AMR::g.test(r2dtable(1, row_tot, col_tot)[[1]] ))
  statistics[i] <- ob$statistic  
  pvals[i] <-  ob$p.value 
}
```

If you make a histogram with `hist(statistics, prob=TRUE, breaks=nclass.FD)` you will see the distribution is quite discrete ...

```r
unique(statistics) |> round(2) |> sort()
 [1]  0.00  0.10  0.13  0.43  0.50  1.00  1.10  1.81  1.94  2.85  3.02  4.15  4.34  5.69  5.92  7.50  7.76  9.58  9.87 11.94
[21] 12.26 14.60 14.96 17.58 17.97 20.91 21.33
```

so for a 2x2-able like this the Fisher exact test is probably better. Calculating the simulated p-value:

```r
mean(statistics >= stat_obs)
[1] 0.393619
mean(statistics > stat_obs)
[1] 0.310455
```

the difference caused by the discreteness. This should not happen with a table larger than 2x2.